# Convert from/to units avoiding large if/switch statements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an if/else block of code that returns the needed number to convert from/to a certain metric unit, for example, it will return `100` if I wanted to convert from `cm` to `mm`.

Here is the actual code: http://plnkr.co/edit/WKutYRbB8d2BFiXvfsBE?p=preview (Lines 24-31).

Now, while the way I'm doing it currently would work, if I had to write all the possible combinations of metric units, I'd end up having a very big and ugly block of if/else statements.

My question is how can I avoid that and make the code smaller/cleaner?

EDIT: Extract important lines here:

```
//TODO: refactor
if(scope.convertFrom == "mm" && scope.convertTo == "in") {
    _mod = 25.4;
}
if(scope.convertFrom == "mm" && scope.convertTo == "ft") {
    _mod = 304.8;
}
//...
```

Comment: Please edit in _lines 24-31_ in the question. Nobody should have to go off-site to solve this issue.

Comment: You could use a library, https://github.com/gentooboontoo/js-quantities ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an object that stores the "weight" of each unit (Note that I'm using the Meter as my oriemtation point so if you want to add Foot or Inch keep that in mind):

```
var units = {
  mm: 0.001,
  cm: 0.01,
  dm: 0.1,
  m: 1,
  km: 1000
}
```

Then write a converting function:

```
function convert(value, fromUnit, toUnit) {
  return value * (units[fromUnit] / units[toUnit])
}
```

Use it like this:

```
convert(42, 'mm', 'cm')
// --> 4.2
```

Comment: I think I'll go that way as using a library is kind of an overkill for what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If a [library](https://github.com/gentooboontoo/js-quantities) isnt' an option.

Make some value e.g. mm the default value and then for each item store a ratio to that one given base unit. You can then keep those values either in the markup or in the code itself.

```
<option value="mm" data-ratio="1">Millimeters</option>
<option value="in" data-ratio="0.0393701">Inches</option>
```

Then in the code

```
var converted = value * (scope.convertFrom.getAttribute('data-ratio') / scope.convertTo.getAttribute('data-ratio'))
```